# Convert/Use API written for C#/Java with PHP

Tags: c#, java, php, api, wsdl

I have access to an API that I would like to use, but it only has documentation in C#/Java. I know neither of these languages and would love to use the API in PHP. I do have access to the API's WSDL and was wondering how I might go about this?

I've heard various other ways such as SOAP calls or converting the WSDL into PHP Classes. Any information is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this can be of help http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: If you are okay to introduce 3rd party libraries as a solution, you can consider http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2php-interpreter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't used Soap's native functions, I have used NuSoap with a WSDL document that's generated from a Java system.  Overall its worked pretty flawlessly; the only problem has been when they've changed how they do authentication and I've had to make some manual changes.  Other than that, I've just had to update the WSDL when they do upgrades.

If I had a newer version, I probably would have just used php's native functions.